# Ionic populating thumbnails with base64 images from a database

Tags: angular, base64, ionic2, sanitization

So i have an object of the type Patient that gets its values from a database and gets a base64 image to use as an avatar but so far the list is displayed correctly with no images and my console logs give me:

"WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value"

My code so far is this:

```
<ion-list danger>
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let patient of patientsList">

       <ion-avatar item-left>
         <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{patient.photo}}">
       </ion-avatar>

        <ion-item (click)="openPage(patient)">
            {{patient.name}}
        </ion-item>


        <ion-item-options>

        <button round (click)="editPatient(patient)" light>
        <ion-icon name="paper"></ion-icon>
        </button>

        <button (click)="deletePatient(patient)">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </button>

        </ion-item-options>

</ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Anybody has a clue of what im doing wrong?

Comment: I personally am doing the same (although storing base64 encoded images in your database is not the best solution). But I bound to the `[src]` like so: `[src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+participant.base64image" ` and this doesn't throw an error/warning

Comment: I think i should try to convert them to JPG and then do it might be a possible solution instead of handling such big URL

Comment: Yep, but that (most of the times) requires your images to be publicly accesible, depends on what you use them for if this becomes an issue or not

Comment: Well its a app for medical purposes with a local storage it doesnt even go online so i dont think it will make any difference hence why im discarting safety measures.

Comment: The way you described actually worked the error is not showing but the images still dont show up any ideias?

Comment: can you add a `base64` encoded image in this plunker? (`page1.ts`) https://plnkr.co/edit/1IX7fG5LvS8l86vHvwlr?p=info

Comment: i got the problem it was that i didnt put it as Ion-item , can you post the answer so i can mark as correct?

Comment: Aah okay haha good that you fixed it, I'll post an answer :)

Comment: @PauloBotelho, this approach is not good. if you using database in firebase for example it can store some part of image data but not all. Why dont you save as file?

Comment: @PauloBotelho maybe problem is not rendering its saving. Confirm that complete data is saved.

Comment: @VinodKumar i didnt want to convert but i think for failsafe proof i will add as a file to the database.

Comment: @PauloBotelho sure- make sense. If you interested check this out - http://vkumar.io/ionic-upload-photo-to-google-firebase-storage/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using the same thing in my project. There I bind to `[src]` like so: `[src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+participant.base64image"`

Although, for storage converting the `base64` image to a normal image and serving them from your backend would be a better solution than storing the `base64` images. (they're quite large). Unless this poses security risks but then again, there are better solutions than storing a `base64` string.

If anyone is facing the same issue, check if you `base64` image is correct in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1IX7fG5LvS8l86vHvwlr)

Answer (score 3):

Paulo Botelho

Only `http`, `https`, `ftp` and `mailto` are safe to use in AngularJS. Angular will prefix a non-whitelisted URL with unsafe: and base 64 string is also considered as unsafe url since it doesn't contain http or any other.

So if you are using angular 2 or angular 4 then you could add following code.

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
...
let sanitizedUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/png;base64,'+patient.photo)
```

then in your html file add this

```
<img src="sanitizedUrl">
```

I hope it would help you.

Comment: You make my day